# JPQL List parameters JPA1

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I'm working on SQl injection using the option of parameters.

i would like to use the following code in my query without the for loop.

```
    List list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("elt1");
  Query  query = "....tab.elt IN (:list)";
    query.setParameter("list", list);
```

I'm using Hibernate 2 , jpa 1 and with the privious code i got an exception

Is there any solution how to deal with this issue ?

UPDATED:

The exception is :

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryTimeoutException: could not execute query     
  at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:124)
  at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2536)   
  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)     
  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)     
  at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:316)
  at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1842)
  at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:165)
  at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:157)    
  at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:246)  
  ... 53 more 
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01460: conversion request not implemented or irrational 
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:70)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:133)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:206)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:455)  
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:413)  
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:1034)    
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:194)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:791)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:866)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1186)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3387)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3431)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1491)
  at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:76)
  at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208)
  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1953)     
  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:802)   
  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2533)
```

Comment: "i got an exception" - if you'd tell us more on the exception (e.g. which exception, the stacktrace etc.) we might be able to help.

Comment: Btw, do you _really_ mean Hibernate _version 2.x_? Afaik Hibernate started to support JPA in version 3.2...

Comment: i updated the post with exception

Comment: The problem seems to originate in the database, i.e. Hibernate seems to be ok with your call. Can you post the query that Hibernate is generating? It's logged as `DEBUG` into the logger `org.hibernate.SQL` (at least in Hibernate 3.x+)